# Float left and clear both are not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put one div below another one, but the code is not working properly. As you can see in the code below, there is the wrapper ("#main"), then the top ("#top"), floating left, and the content ("#content"), floating left and clearing left also. Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="top">

            </div>
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; <!-- Already tried putting fixed height -->
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: #999999;
    position: absolute; <!-- Already tried removing this line -->
    display: block; <!-- Already tried removing this line and the same one from #top-->
    float: left; <!-- Already tried removing this line -->
    clear: left; <!-- Already tried clear:both -->
}
```

But, for some reason, the grey div is not going under the red one. I have no idea what is happening. Please find below the image that is showing on my browser.

[image]

Comment: I think you want "clear: both;" not clear: left;

Comment: Already tried also... Not working

Comment: also why do you have the position as absolute? try not defining a position, and just do float left;

Comment: you should provide feedback or accept an answer so we know if we helped or not

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #999999;
    float: left;
    clear: both; 
}
```

and if you want the "content" to be to the right more, you can do something else:

```
#content {
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #999999;
 clear: both; 
 //NOTE MARGIN 0 auto will center the div for you
 margin: 0 auto;
 // or set a margin yourself ex:
 margin: 0 5px 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work... I solved the problem using jQuery to calculate the margins dynamically when the page loads... Was the only way I found to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

As top is positioned absoulte you cant clear left,

try reomving this property form #top

```
 position:absolute;
```

and from #content remove

```
 position:absolute;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: when I remove

```
position:absolute
```

from `#top` and `#content`, the `#top` loses its height property. Also, a small white margin appears on Chrome. The only solution I found was to include `position:absolute` and `top:0; and left:0;`

The code I'm using now is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="top">
                <p>aaa</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #999999;
    float: left;
    clear: both; 
}
```

But I want the `#top` to fill all the page when the page loads, and then the user has more content when he scrolls down.

Please find an image of actual page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVteq.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="top">
            TOP
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            BOTTOM
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /**as you are giving here a 100% height you need to place some content inside the div **/
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
    float: left;   
}

#content {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;    
    background-color: #999999;
    margin:0 auto;      
}
```

Yo can see a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/SoniaGM/ecu3fuzy/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to remove top white line

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Position absolute consists from browser window in both left and top positions.

Please find the html and css code

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }       

        #main{
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             margin:0 auto;
             background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        #content{
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #999999;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">           
           <div id="top">
               TOP
            </div>
            <div id="content">
              content
            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply translate it with translateY. Here's the solution:

`#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; <!-- Already tried putting fixed height -->
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}`

`#content{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 25%;
    background-color: #999999;
    position:relative;
    transform: translateY(150%);
}`